# prove that [p!/(p-4)!] + 1 is a perfect square for all natural p.

Tags: factorial, factoring, square-numbers

one can observe that $[p!/(p-4)!] + 1$ is basically the product of four consecutive integers plus one.Since this is 
$$ 
\begin{eqnarray} p(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)+1 & = &(p^2+3p)(p^2+3p+2)+1 \\
 & = & [(p^2+3p+1)−1][(p^2+3p+1)+1]+1 \\
 & = & (p^2+3p+1)^2 \end{eqnarray} $$
which is a perfect square for all natural $p$ but my teacher says that there is a more elegant method of doing it, help in any form would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you say n when you meant to say p in your title?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  Did you mean for all natural $p$?

Comment: yes I'm sorry for the typo

Comment: Are you sure that it is $p(p+1)(p+2)(p+3)+1$ and not $p(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)+1$?

Comment: yes @user170039

Comment: Then it is clearly wrong.

Comment: what is wrong? @user170039

Comment: You are using $p$ and $n$ in confusing ways, Your target seems to be the product of four consecutive integers plus one. But these integers are named inconsistently.

Comment: Your computation appears to be working with $\frac {(p+4)!}{p!}+1$ instead of what you wrote.  Doesn't change much, but it makes your post unhelpfully confusing.

Comment: Recall that $p!=1\times2\times\ldots\times p$.

Answer (score 3):

Only thing I can see:

Note that $p(p-3)=p^2-3p$  and $(p-1)(p-2)=p^2-3p+2$.  It follows that we can write your expression as 
$$(p^2-3p)^2+2(p^2-3p)+1=m^2+2m+1=(m+1)^2$$
Where we have introduced $m=p^2-3p$ ,

Comment: some of my classmates have done it like that.

Comment: This is pretty much the same as has been done in the question with a change of sign. Introducing $m$ makes it a little clearer.

Comment: is there any other way?

Comment: @MarkBennet  Maybe so.  The point I was trying to make (maybe unsuccessfully, and maybe it wasn't all that good a point to begin with) was that it all hinges on the fact that $p^2-3p$ appears twice in the product.  If it's unhelpful, I'll gladly delete.

Comment: @lulu no, helpful, definitely.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different approach... where $p=q+3$

$$S_q=\frac{(p)!}{(p-4)!}+1=\frac{(q+3)!}{(q-1)!} + 1=q(q+1)(q+2)(q+3)+1$$

Let $q=a-\frac{3}{2}$

Then

$$S_q=\left(a-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(a-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(a+\frac{3}{2}\right)+1$$

$$S_q=\left(a^2-\frac{3^2}{2^2}\right)\left(a^2-\frac{1}{2^2}\right)+1$$

$$S_q=a^4-\frac{10}{4}a^2+\frac{3^2}{4^2}+1$$

$$S_q=a^4-\frac{10}{4}a^2+\frac{5^2}{4^2}$$

$$S_q=\left(a^2-\frac{5}{4} \right)^2$$

$$S_q=\left((q+3/2)^2-\frac{5}{4} \right)^2$$

$$S_p=\left((p-3/2)^2-\frac{5}{4} \right)^2$$

Comment: I think this is what my teacher expected.

Comment: @MaryTom It then takes just a little bit of thought to know that if an integer is the square of a rational number, it is the square of an integer. Or to expand the expression in the bracket and see that it is an integer. It is not quite immediately obvious that the expression in the final bracket is an integer.